# how to change filterContext.IsChildAction value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributes

I know that IsChildAction  is read-only , But anyway i uses from a partial view.  i call it with Html.Action . 
when i use from Html.Action my filterContext.IsChildAction equls false .
i have a Attribute and i override OnActionExecuting . 
this is my code

```
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {


      //  filterContext.IsChildAction = false;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                    )
                    );
            filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);


            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);



    }
```

my friend i want redirect to another page when i call a Child Action . so i create a Attribute Class and Inheritance from ActionFilterAttribute Class.

but when use from Html.action i get this error

```
Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions.
```

Comment: Child actions are for generating content to put into a main view. It makes no sense to have a child action do a redirect (imagine how hard it would be to find bugs in pages that have child actions that redirect). The simple answer is to put your attribute that redirects on the main action, not the child action.

Comment: okay tank you  NightOwl888 . Now I will want submit a form . when i click insert button my request is a Http post . i want use this attribute over the public ActionResult Create () . this is post  and this is child action too. and my create uses ajax request . do you understand my question Now NightOwl888 ? i do have way for resolve it. :(